# Python generate all unique permutations and no sorted repeats [Fixed, I meant to look for combinations]

Tags: python, algorithm

Edit: I confused the difference between permutations and combinations. Edited the question just to keep it up (as I can't delete it). Though I realized my mistake.

I've been browsing this question around for a bit and I couldn't find a solution that fits uniquely to what I'm looking for.

The basic concept is if I ran a function `gen_permutations([1,2])` to generate permutations. I would get the result `([1,2],[2,1])`, though in this result, I would classify they are the same set.

I would think of checking something as `result[0] < result[1]` then add it to the set of results. Though, how would this be scaled up for example `gen_permutations(input, size=n | n <= len(input))`?

Sorry if there's a question answered to this, but all "Similar Questions" point me to just "unique results" where [1,2] != [2,1].

Edit: Case for confusion, the function `gen_permutations` is  just a generic generator that I found and used here [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python?rq=1)

Another example to make it bigger. I could run this case

```
for i in permutations([1,2,3,4],3):
    print i
```

Gets the result 
`(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4),(1, 3, 2),(1, 3, 4),(1, 4, 2),(1, 4, 3),(2, 1, 3),(2, 1, 4),(2, 3, 1),(2, 3, 4),(2, 4, 1),(2, 4, 3),(3, 1, 2),(3, 1, 4),(3, 2, 1),(3, 2, 4),(3, 4, 1),(3, 4, 2),(4, 1, 2),(4, 1, 3),(4, 2, 1),(4, 2, 3),(4, 3, 1),(4, 3, 2)`

Though `(1,2,3)` and `(3,2,1)` I would consider not unique. Since if you reordered them they would be the same set. I need help to code a generator of permutations that would not generate the result `(3,2,1)` as `(1,2,3)` was already generated.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear: you want permutations but not all of them ? Which one do you exclude ? You could add more examples to clarify too.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you have a function `gen_permutations()` or are you asking how to write one?

Comment: A permutation is just an ordering of the elements in a set. The only output that makes sense for the function you are asking for is to wrap the input in other list: `get_permutations([1,2]) = [[1,2]]`.

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)? In maths, combinations don't care about order so [1,2] is equal to [2,1]. [This article](https://betterexplained.com/articles/easy-permutations-and-combinations/) explains more.

In python you can simply do:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations([1,2], 2))
```

Which gives the output:

```
[(1,2)]
```

Comment: An explanation of the difference between [combinations and permutations](https://betterexplained.com/articles/easy-permutations-and-combinations/). With combinations, order doesn't matter, which seems to be what you want here.

Comment: Yep exactly what I wanted. I completely forgot about the difference. I was too honed into "generate all possibilities". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In permutations the order matters, so `[1,2]` is different than `[2,1]`.

It seems that what you want are **combinations**, and python has buildin support for it.

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.combinations('ABCD', 2))
```

The result is:

```
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
```

You can also iterate through the results since itertools.combinations() returns an iterator.

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.combinations('ABCD', 2):
    print i
```

Result:

```
('A', 'B')
('A', 'C')
('A', 'D')
('B', 'C')
('B', 'D')
('C', 'D')
```